# .htaccess difficulties with directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to following url :

`nl/provincies/Limburg/plaats/#CITY#`
for example : 
`nl/provincies/Limburg/plaats/Amsterdam`

To be rewriten to `section.php?sid=plaatsen$plaats=#CITY#`

Ofcourse this is not so difficult by using :

`^nl/provincies/plaatsen/(.*)$  section.php?sid=plaatsend&plaats=$1`

But the problem comes when I also want to do this for :

`nl/provincies/#STATE#`

for example : 

`nl/provincies/Limburg`

To be rewriten to `section.php?sid=plaatsen$province=#STATE#`

Now the problem comes and this does not work.
It sees provincies/Limburg/plaats/Echt

As one province, the province : Limburg/plaats/Echt

I tried to be creative and used :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^nl/provincies/plaats/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^provincies/(.*)$ section.php?sid=plaatsen&province=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^nl/provincies/plaats/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^nl/provincies/plaatsen/(.*)$   section.php?sid=plaatsend&plaats=$1
```

Any ideas / solutions ? Thanks guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^nl/provincies/plaatsen/(.*)$ section.php?sid=plaatsend&plaats=$1
```

...this will never match the URL you've given?

Anyway what you're looking for is something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/provincies/([^/]+)$         section.php?sid=plaatsend&plaats=$2
RewriteRule ^(.+)/provincies/.+/plaats/(.+)$  section.php?sid=plaatsend&province=$2
```

Or more generic:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/provincies/([^/]+)(/plaats/)?(.+)?$ section.php?sid=plaatsend&province=$2&plaats=$4&locale=$1
```

For complex rewriting like this I would however sincerely recommend [doing it in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16389034/1729885).

Comment: Niels, really apriciated your post. Many thanks ! Yes, I did see that it does not match.

But you already gave me the right answer.
([^/]+) is that a wildcard for every directory except plaats ?

Also you mixed up the section.php, they should be otherwise.

Comment: Really works excellent Niels ! 
This solutions popped up 2 questions :

What is $1 and $2 in your example.
Because I only see $1 as the province or place

([^/] stands for a directory which comes after provincies ?
This can be everydirectory except place ? Right ?

Comment: a) Read up on regexps  ;)   `[^/]` matches any character except the slash. b) $1 and $2 refer to the first and second match (the parenthesized blocks in the regexp, like `(.+)`. I think those 2 additions should answer all questions  :)  My 'more generic' solution just makes a lot of things optional with the `?` suffix, ensuring all URLs can be passed through the same regexp.